# How to create a "Conditional String" using recursion

Tags: java, string, eclipse, recursion

i'm trying to implement a `toString()` method to print the preorder traversal of an AVL tree. I want to print the int or char in the node but if it doesn't exist, then print a dash( `-` ). So far, this is my code.

```
public String toString() {
    if(root != null) {
        AVLNode<T> node = root;
        String result = "";
        return preorder(node, result);
    }else {
        return "Empty root";
    }

}

private String preorder(AVLNode<T> root, String result) {
    result = result + root.getElement().toString();
    if(nodeCheckLeft(root)) {
        preorder(root.getLeft(), result);
    }else {
        result = result + "-";
    }

    if(nodeCheckRight(root)) {
        preorder(root.getRight(), result);
    }else {
        result = result +"-";
    }
    return result;
}
```

nodeCheck is a suplementary method that I use to know if the node is empty.

The expected results would be:

`Adding{'b'}             --> "b--"`

`Adding{'b','a'}         --> "ba---"`

`Adding{'b','a','d'}     --> "ba--d--"`

`Adding{'b','a','d','c'} --> "ba--dc--"`

Here is a full test:

```
    @Test
void testAdd() {
    AVLTree<Character> a = new AVLTree <Character>();

    a.add('b');
    assertEquals("b--", a.toString());
    a.add('a');
    assertEquals("ba---", a.toString());
    a.add('d');
    assertEquals("ba--d--", a.toString());
    a.add('c');
    assertEquals("ba--dc--", a.toString());
    a.add('g');
    assertEquals("ba--dc--g--", a.toString());
    a.add('i');
    assertEquals("ba--dc--g-i--", a.toString());
    a.add('h');
    assertEquals("ba--dc--g-ih---", a.toString());

}
```

What I get in line 4 is `b-`. I assume (I might be wrong) that the problem is that since the string gets changed on "deeper" branches of the recursion, the main branch, which is the one that returns the resultant string to the `toString()` method, doesn't get updated. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: AVLNode is your own class ?

Comment: Yes, it is my own class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in Java are immutable. What this means is that you never actually *change* a string, you just create a new one and now your variable points at that instead.

In particular, the line `result = result + "-";` won't change the string you originally passed. The variable `result`, in that particular function call, now holds a completely different string which is then returned. This does not affect the value of `result` in the outer call, and in fact nothing is done with that returned string.

The fix is just assigning the returned string back to `result`, like so: `result = preorder(root.getLeft(), result);`

Comment: I changed the code just like you told me and now it passes every test until I add 'c'.

It should be"ba--dc---" but instead I get "ba--c--". Any clue on why it gets changed?

Comment: Is your test case correct? It seems like it should be `ba--dc---` since c has two empty children and d still has another empty one.

Comment: Yes, thats the expected result: --> a.add('c'); -->
    assertEquals("ba--dc--", a.toString());

The thing is it returns ba--c--

Comment: It's strange that the d node is not showing up at all. My guess is that there might be a bug in your AVL code causing the d node to be replaced entirely with c. That output seems consistent with that.

Comment: Yeah I just found an error in my add method. I didn't think of looking there before because that was part of the code implemented by the teacher but I guess everyone makes mistakes now and then. It's works perfectly now, thank you ^^